# rss-feed doesn't appear correctly in flipboard

Tags: xml, atom-feed, flipboard

## I have encountered some problems while making mine rss-feed for flipboard.

There is one russian site [vesti.ru](http://vesti.ru) with abolutely ugly [rss-feed](http://www.vesti.ru/vesti.rss). It has cp-1251 encoding, many enclosures for one post and so on - beee.

But this site provides prety interesting news feed, so I've decided to reparse it's rss-feed to make it friendly for flipboard. I've used PyAtom. and my app is now running on heroku. Rss-feed located [here](http://flipboardfriendly.herokuapp.com/vesti_ru)

### What is my problem:

I can read [my feed](http://flipboardfriendly.herokuapp.com/vesti_ru) in google reader and in flipboard throught google reader's feed as well. But I can't get mine feeds items in flipboard natively , not using google reader.

Flipboard always says to me : **"no items"** (but shows feeds titles correctly)

I thought that it's some kind of heroku restictions, and tried to load my feed in flipboard from my [dropbox public page](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/60606921/zrss.xml) , but got failed again.

Please, help me figure out why flipboard rejects to show my feed and always says **"no items"**

Thnx

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use your reader account and open the feed in flipboard, then press the `+` icon and now have the feed directly to you flipboard account?